# After modifying input value, css style disappear

Tags: javascript, css, input

I am a beginner of javascript learner.
I'm blocked by this problems for days without any solution, here is my demo:[create invitee from](https://jsfiddle.net/subrina/yofyfzm7/)

Here is the process:

1.enter some texts in the bar and hit submit button

2.you will get a box where you will see two buttons: edit button and remove button

3.please click edit button to toggle between edit mode and save mode

my problem is, once I modified the input value in the invitee box, the css disappeared, and when I inspected the html file, I notice that `<div class="row justify-content-center" id="guestsList">` has be changed to `<div class="col-5 item" id="guestsList">`

I totally have no clue about what is going on and how to fix it,if anyone can give me some advice that will be great! thanks for your help

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: `list.className = "col-5";`

Comment: What is that you want to fix? The reason why its happening is because of      if (checked) {
      list.className = "col-5";
      list.className += " item-choose";
    } else {
      list.className = "col-5";
      list.className += " item";
    }

Comment: sorry I still don't understand why `<div class="row justify-content-center" id="guestsList">` has changed to `<div class="col-5 item" id="guestsList">`,is there anybody can explain how it work to me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the css for that fancy box is inside the `row` class.

And you reset the class in the eventListener here:

```
if (checked) {
  list.className = "col-5";
  list.className += " item-choose";
} else {
  list.className = "col-5";
  list.className += " item";
}
```

You can make a nice method for adding and removing classes like this:

```
function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.add(className)
  else if (!hasClass(el, className)) el.className += " " + className
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.remove(className)
  else if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')
    el.className=el.className.replace(reg, ' ')
  }
}
```

And then try this instead:

```
if (checked) {
  addClass(list, "item-choose");
} else {
  removeClass(list, "item-choose");
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/yofyfzm7/2/

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can mark it as correct. Good luck!